# Protect against unary operator expected error when no return value?

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, unary-operator

How do I protect against this type of error  `./checkConfigs.sh: line 22: [: -gt: unary operator expected` when my command statement only sometimes returns an integer value?

```
duplicatesConfig=`sort ${dirNames[0]}"$bf" | uniq -cd | sort -nr | awk '{sum+=$1} END{ print sum}'`
duplicatesBox=`sort ${dirNames[1]}"$bf" | uniq -cd | sort -nr | awk '{sum+=$1} END{ print sum}'`
if [ $duplicatesConfig -gt 0 ]
then
    createCopy ${dirNames[0]}"$bf" 0
fi
if [ $duplicatesBox-gt 0 ]
then
    createCopy ${dirNames[1]}"$bf" 1
fi
done
```

Line 22 is the first if statement.

I am using awk to capture a sum of all of the duplicates lines in my file. The code works perfectly when I the duplicate count is > 0 but it throws that error when there is no duplicates. The code doesn't break but I would like to prevent that error from popping up.

Comment: *"`The code works perfectly`"*. Really? I always get an error for `[ 1-gt 2 ]`. Put a space before `-gt`. Like so: `[ "$duplicatesBox" -gt 0 ]`

Comment: @EdMorton Will do

Answer (score 1):

Change `print sum` to `print sum+0` so you always get a number output from awk.

Also, copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the shell issues it tells you about.